# Calling a Function to Pass Iteration to the Function

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is make use of a function I have already created in a separate Javascript file. That file contains the following and we will call it scripttwo:

```
function assignLetterGrade(score)
{
 var letterGrade;

 if (score > 89)
      letterGrade = 'A';
 else if (score > 79)
      letterGrade = 'B';
 else if (score > 69)
      letterGrade = 'C';
 else if (score > 59)
      letterGrade = 'D';
 else
      letterGrade = 'F';

 return letterGrade; 
 }

/**Returns a letter grade for the score, either "A", "B", "C", "D", or "F".
*Return A if numeric score is 90 to 100
*Return B if numeric score is 80 to 89
*Return C if numeric score is 70 to 79
*Return D if numeric score is 60 to 69
*Return F if numeric score is less than 60
*/
```

I need to create a new Javascript file named scripts.js and create a function named assignLetterGrades this function will have a loop that iterates from 58 to 100. Here is what I have so far:

```
function assignLetterGrades(){

    for (e = 58; e <= 100; e = e + 1) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Now with each iteration I need to call my assignLetterGrade and pass it the iteration number to assignLetterGrade which I then want it to display the corresponding letter grade. It should look something like "A numeric score of 59 is equivalent to a letter grade of F" and I need to call the function assignLetterGrades once from my main html file.

I have just about the entire thing done I'm just stuck on how to get my results to come up. I had the following which showed up everything besides the letter grade:

```
function assignLetterGrades(){

    for (e = 58; e <= 100; e = e + 1) {
        document.write("A numeric score of " + e + " is equivalent to a letter grade 
        of " + "<br>");
    }
}
```

I'm confused and stuck on how to get the letter grade to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before scripts.js load your scripttwo in the script tag  in the HTML file and  you can use the function without any issue

```
function assignLetterGrades(){
    for (e = 58; e <= 100; e = e + 1) {
        assignLetterGrade(e);
    }

}

function assignLetterGrades(){

    for (e = 58; e <= 100; e = e + 1) {
        document.write("A numeric score of " + e + " is equivalent to a letter grade 
        of " + assignLetterGrade(e)+”<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out almost 5+ hours. Can't tell I'm a newbie... :(

Answer (score 0):

Include both javascript files in your index.html

and both scripts will be available

```
function assignLetterGrades(){

    for (e = 58; e <= 100; e = e + 1) {
        document.write("A numeric score of " + e + " is equivalent to a letter grade of " + assignLetterGrade(e)+"<br>");
    }
}

assignLetterGrades()
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpqK5EQptxrEv15XKPR4?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an array to store the corresponding letter grade at index `score`.
The array would look like:

```
var letterGrades = [ 'F', 'F', 'F', ..., 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', ...];
```

To get that array, we can use a function that will generate it:

```
function generateLetterGrades() {
  var grades = [];
  var letters = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'];

  for (let i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    grades[i] = letters[Math.floor(i / 10)] || letters[9];
  }
  return grades;
}
```

The `grades` array returned here will look like `letterGrades` mentioned previously.

Now, inside `assignLetterGrades`, we will just generate a `letterGrades` array and loop over it *(wether using `[].forEach()` or a `for` loop)* to get the wanted result.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function generateLetterGrades() {
  var grades = [];
  var letters = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'];
  
  for (let i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    grades[i] = letters[Math.floor(i / 10)] || letters[9];
  }
  return grades;
}

function assignLetterGrades() {
  var letterGrades = generateLetterGrades();
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  
  // Can be changed into a for loop if needed
  letterGrades.forEach((letter, i) => {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add(letter);
    div.textContent = "A numeric score of " + i + " is equivalent to a letter grade of " + letter;
    container.appendChild(div);
  });
  /* Alternative
     for (let i = 0; i < letterGrades.length; i++) {
       let letter = letterGrades[i];
       // The same body as above goes here...
     }
   */
}

assignLetterGrades();
```

```css
div div {
  margin: .2em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

.A {
  background: gold;
}

.B {
  background: #76ed76;
}

.C {
  background: #8cd2f2;
}

.D {
  background: #e6a8f7;
}

.F {
  background: #f48686;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```